# gitlab runner error with environment

Tags: debian, gitlab, gitlab-runner

I have installed a new gitlab runner and am getting an error.

```
ERROR: Job failed: prepare environment: Process exited with status 1. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

my file /home/gitlab-runner/.bash_logout is empty.
My config:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "server2"
  url = "https://gitlab.domain.com/"
  id = 41
  token = ""
  token_obtained_at = 2023-04-20T07:10:16Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "gitlab"
    host = "server.dns.name"
    port = "22"
    identity_file = "/data/gitlab/.ssh/id_ed25519"
    disable_strict_host_key_checking = true
```

Same config (except token and connection info)  works fine on other runners. I rollback version on 15.6.1 (this version installed on other runners). User gitlab like a user gitlab-runner not  have .bash_logout.
Used proxmox 7.3-6 as runner (based on debian 11).
What a problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, also need remove .bashrc file